Power Automate and Dataverse - twice the same row ID in one flow
I'm having a flow with 2 new rows created in a Dataverse table.
Both rows have correct data, but the ID generated (which is an autonumber) are the same for both rows. In between both rows, there is an approval flow.
Here is the flow:
Flow
And here are the rows created:
Rows
Can someone explain why there rows have the same ID?
Thank you very much

can you show what your parameters are for each dataverse action?

Well, the ID is set to null, in order to trigger the autonumber
